# Deploy code on multiple servers from same branch

Tags: php, git, amazon-web-services, capistrano

This is my situation.

I have a project that has always been deployed on a single server. Our situation has changed, now the project is deployed on several servers internationally. We still have only one branch that we deploy so far. The project now contains generic code but also country-specific code.

I want to change that but I do not know how. There are two possibilities for me. The first is to create one branch per country from my origin one. But before that I have to do some cleaning work to isolate the generic code and leave that specific code for each country. The disadvantage of this solution is that people can quickly be lost between many branches.

[image]

The second solution is to keep a single branch but I must update the code to create generic controllers that will redirect to specific controllers depending on the country.

[image]

I am interested, if you think there are other solutions to remedy this problem.

Comment: If you are using same branch for all servers, you can use `rsync` to copy code between multiple servers.

Comment: There are many approaches to this. May I suggest you read a book called The Phoenix Project and start doing research on DEVOPS along with CICD.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Let me try to help with a real world example. I have an application that I deployed to multiple servers in AWS. The servers are running behind a load balancer and are based in different availability zones. I use Github and have a master branch where the source code for the application goes. I use AWS Codedeploy to push changes from the Github master branch to all of the servers. In reality, when I commit to master, it pushes the commit to code deploy which will write the new master branch to the code directory on each of the servers, one at a time. There are many similar tools available to us.

Comment: Also, I am very much suggesting to keep the application in one branch and rather make it so that the application can detect the country that it is operating in (say by server ip) and then do whatever based on that outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that git is a source control tool, and structures like branches are intended to solve source control problems.  Someone long ago observed that because git has a protocol for transmitting changes to a remote repo, it could be used as a deployment tool; and in very simple cases, it can do that job well.  But too often people start off with this, and then as their build/deployment requirements become more complex they expect git to scale with that.  Which it probably would, if it were a build and deployment tool.  But it's not.

The downside to "branch per country" is not merely that people could get lost among the branches.  The bigger downside is that keeping the common code in sync across all branches will be tedious and, ultimately, will probably not happen reliably.

Your other solution is perhaps better, but it treats identification of country as a dynamic run-time decision, when in fact it could be decided at deployment time (since clearly a given deployed instance is either always in country-1, or always in country-2, or ...).

Why not use build and deployment tools that can support multiple configurations, so that you can use a single code base and let the tools construct the correct version of the site for any given server?

Comment: This is not a problem of configuration but features that are different .

Comment: What makes you think needing different code is not a configuration issue?